# Remove / sign from url within Category

Tags: .htaccess

Help!!, I have tried by best more than a day trying to fix this, Please I want to redirect all search query url within a category and also removing the / sign from the url using htaccess e.g `example.com/stack/?s=keyword/` to `example.com/stack/?s=keyword`

I have tried the below code but its only redirecting `example.com/?s=keyword/` to `example.com/?s=keyword` but it is not working when I include the category url to the permalink.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=([^&]+)/$
RewriteRule ^$ /?s=%1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Please I need help here please I beg of you please.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule as your topmost rule:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} (/stack/\?s=[^&\s]*)/\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301,NE]
```

Comment: here is another way I figure out myself, I really appreciate your time

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/stack/
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} s=([^&]+)/$
 RewriteRule (.*) /stack/?s=%1 [R=302,L,NE]
</IfModule>`

Comment: thanks alot. I will use yours because it is shorter.